# New Swift for-in syntax for incrementing and decrementing loops

Tags: swift, swift2, for-in-loop

TL;DR; Why doesn't the Swift range operator handle decreasing ranges?

I have some code like this:

```
for var i = 0; i < previousPage; i += 1 {
    purgePage(i)
}
```

Which the swift compiler suggests I change to the [new Swift for loop](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md) syntax:

```
C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift
Fix-it Replace "var i = 0; i < previousPage; i += 1" with "i in 0 ..< previousPage"
```

The resulting code now looks like this:

```
// Purge previous non-visible pages.
for i in 0 ..< previousPage {
    purgePage(i)
}
```

The problem is that now the app crashes because `previousPage` can be a negative or a positive integer, forming either an increasing or decreasing range. When it's a decreasing range, I get the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`:

```
fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start
```

How can I make the new syntax work in my case? Adding code to check the value of `previousPage` seems to be a step backwards from the old syntax.

Comment: Make sure previousPage is at least 0 `max(0,previousPage)`

Comment: Yes, but adding code to check `previousPage` seems like something that the range operator should do for free.

Comment: What result do you expect if `previousPage` is negative? (Your original code would do *zero* iterations, it does not decrement `i` in that case.)

Comment: @MartinR yes i notice that as well.And it is sound like what work around is for that case.

Comment: I expected that the loop would not iterate, this behaviour is useful if I need to do something if there is a previous page, and do nothing if there is no previous page, i.e. we're on the first page. I don't consider this a side effect, do you? Maybe I'm just used to this free behaviour of C for-loops.

Comment: You can also add a where clause and make your code more clear

Comment: What would you expect `0...previousPage` to do if `previousPage` were negative? Should it count backwards (I think many people would expect that, but then it would be inconsistent with your expectation of `..<`). What should `x..<y` do if `x` and `y` are not `Comparable`? (`x` can be a `ForwardIndexType` only). There are lots of corner cases that you create if you allow this to work the way you say you expect, so there's no "obvious" answer. Swift *could* have done it, but "why" questions are open ended, speculative, and not well suited to Stack Overflow. The answer is "because it doesn't."

Comment: These are all valid suggestions, though my question more refers to why, from a language design perspective, the behaviour of simply not iterating a negative range was not added to the range operator.

Comment: @Rop Napier, thanks for your explanation. In the case of `0...previousPage`, I would expect it to iterate backwards, and in the case of `0..<previousPage`, that it not iterate at all. I'll look into the corner cases you mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't the Swift range operator handle decreasing ranges?

I believe I read a statement from a Swift team member (probably [@jckarter](https://twitter.com/jckarter)) that they deliberately designed `Range` in this way to avoid a likely source of programmer errors. The reasoning was that more often than not, when you create a range from variables (not literals) like `a..<b`, you'd implicitly assume `a <= b`. `Range` is designed to trap if that assumption is violated to make the (possible) error obvious to you.

I can't find the reference at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks @Ole Begemann, this seems like the most likely explanation. BTW I was just reading your blog on ranges and intervals.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stride` instead of range. It won't crash in this case.

```
0.stride(to: previousPage, by: 1).forEach { purgePage($0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

From error it is possible to conclude that loop is going in wrong direction example 0..-4 or from 6...1.

To solve problem it is possible to use do while, it is not the greatest solution but it is simple and clear:

```
var i = 0;

while i < previousPage{
    i += 1
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: I stated in the question the reason _why_ it wasn't working (namely, the fact that it decrements), but this and other workarounds do not seem like a step up from the old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to manually add a condition before the loop. Functionally, this should work similar to C-style loops; however, it's not as concise syntactically:

```
if (previousPage > 0)
{
    // Purge previous non-visible pages.
    for i in 0 ..< previousPage {
        purgePage(i)
    }
}
```